# How I can solve this equation in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: continuity

Let us consider the following equation in $\mathbb{C}$

$$f(s)g(s)=0$$

Assume that $f,g:\mathbb{C}→\mathbb{R}$, then they are not analytic, but they are probably continuous in some subdomains of $\mathbb{C}$.

My question is how I can solve the above equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions consist of those $s$ satsifying $f(s)=0$ or $g(s)=0$. Without knowing what $f$ and $g$ are, you can't say anything more than that.

Note: this has nothing to do with complex-analysis.